# curl failing if used with && in terminal

Tags: macos, curl, terminal

I'm currently trying to write a one line string that automatically installs the latest version of wget on a Mac if copy and pasted into terminal. The problem is curl seems to be failing with an unresolved host error after successfully downloading the file only when I use && with another command.

Here is an example:

curl -O ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.15.tar.gz

This downloads with no error.

curl -O ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.15.tar.gz && tar -zxvf wget-1.15.tar.gz

This fails with 'curl: (6) Could not resolve host:', but the file is downloaded successfully. I can extract it and continue installing manually no problem.

This is on curl 7.30.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Works for me as written. Are you doing something to complicate matters, like trying to store the command in a variable?

Comment: No variables are being used. I'm using those exact code fragments. It seems to work only once every 20-30 attempts for me. I've also tried switching to one of their mirror URLs and ran into the same problem.

Comment: Does it work if you paste it directly into Terminal?

Comment: Only the first command 'curl -O ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.15.tar.gz' works when pasted directly into terminal. The other one, 'curl -O ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.15.tar.gz && tar -zxvf wget-1.15.tar.gz' fails when pasted directly into terminal with 'curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ' and does not continue to the 'tar -zxvf wget-1.15.tar.gz' portion of the command.

Comment: For whatever reason, running curl in verbose causes the second line to work without a problem. It only fails with verbose turned off.

Comment: If you want to debug further, try using `set -x` to see how the shell is parsing the commands -- it should show any differences in how curl is being run between the two versions of the command. (You can use `set +x` to turn it off.)